# Powershell script: works when written by hand, doesn't work when generated.

Tags: powershell

I have a disk operation which I would like to automate with a Powershell script called `test.ps1` which looks like this:

```
diskpart /s diskstuff.txt
```

The file diskstuff.txt looks like this:

```
list disk
select disk 0
list partition
```

When I create `diskstuff.txt` by hand using notepad.exe, and then run it like this:

```
PS C:\> powershell.exe .\test.ps1
```

It runs fine, giving me information about the partitions. But I want just one file to deal with. So I tried this script in `test2.ps1`:

```
$text1 = 'list disk'
$text2 = 'select disk 0'
$text3 = 'list partition'
$text1 > 'diskstuff2.txt'
$text2 >> 'diskstuff2.txt'
$text3 >> 'diskstuff2.txt'
diskpart /s diskstuff2.txt
```

When I ran the script with:

```
PS C:\> powershell.exe .\test2.ps1
```

It didn't return anything useful from **diskpart**. I inspected `diskstuff2.txt` and `diskstuff.txt` in **notepad.exe**, and it looked exactly the same.

I looked around the 'net a bit, and found a better way to inspect the files. First a dump of the handcoded file (`diskstuff.txt`).

```
PS C:\> Get-Content diskstuff.txt -Encoding Byte
```

The last few lines of the result were

```
116
105
111
110
13
10
```

Then a dump of the generated file (`diskstuff2.txt`)

```
PS C:\> Get-Content diskstuff.txt -Encoding Byte
```

The last few lines of the result were:

```
116
0
105
0
111
0
110
0
13
0
10
0
```

This showed that my script to generate diskstuff2.txt was somehow inserting zeros between every character. Is there a way I can get my script to generate `diskstuff2.txt` without all of those zeros, so that I can execute `test2.ps1` as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection operators `>` and `>>` use UTF-16 encoding for files. If you need different encoding, then you should use `Out-File` or `Set-Content`/`Add-Content` cmdlets. All have `-Encoding` parameter to specify encoding.

--------update by Jay-----------
This was the correct approach. The final answer for `test2.ps1` was:

```
$text1 = 'list disk'
$text2 = 'select partition 0'
$text3 = 'list partition'
Set-Content -Path diskstuff2.txt -Value $text1 -Encoding UTF8
Add-Content -Path diskstuff2.txt -Value $text2 -Encoding UTF8
Add-Content -Path diskstuff2.txt -Value $text3 -Encoding UTF8
diskpart /s diskstuff2.txt
```